# Copy subfolders with specific (same) name to destination

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

Wrapping my head around following problem - also trying to illustrate what I try to achieve.

Source contains Subfolders named "import", which contain files and/or folders - (only) this "import"-folders should be copied to a destination directory with new individual names, as there can be only one folder with same name of course.

```
.Source
├── FolderA
│   └── import
│       └── Attachment
│   └── log
│
├── FolderB
│   └── import
│   └── log
│
├── FolderC
│   └── import
│       └── Attachment
│   └── log
```

.

```
.Destination
├── import27526
│   └── Attachment
│
├── import96385
│
├── import52987
│   └── Attachment
```

I tried to solve this in CMD with FOR and xcopy or robocopy, creating random destination-directories.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a:d /b /s "import"') do (xcopy /y /i /S "%%A" "C:\temp\%%~nxA%random%")
```

Unfortunately it's not working, as all data from within various "import"-source folders is copied in a single destination directory instead of individual ones.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you've posted as code is not a [tag:cmd] command line, it is a [tag:batch-file] command line. Please revisit the question, to adjust the code and/or tags to match, thank you. Also, as you've already stated that you don't want to have two directories with the same name, what makes you think that `%RANDOM%` will never output a numeric string matching an already existing one? It would make more sense to name them `FolderA_import`, `FolderB_import`, `FolderC_import` etc.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for clarification, I changed the tags. The copied folders will be processed and deleted within a couple of minutes from the destination directory, so I thought the chances of a same random value are pretty small. But yes, I agree that it would make morse sense to name the folders in the pattern you described indeed.

Comment: The core problem of your code fragment – besides possible duplicates of random numbers – is lack of [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for the random number…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based upon my comment and your response, the following [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) should work for you:

```batch-file
@For /D %%G In (".Source\*") Do @%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe "%%G\import" ".Destination\%%~nxG_import">NUL
```

From [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```batch-file
For /D %G In (".Source\*") Do @%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe "%G\import" ".Destination\%~nxG_import">NUL
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you first of all!! I added /S to the robocopy command, so subdirectories within the "import" directories are copied as well, now its working as expected!

Comment: That was probably wise @Stefanski, I just didn't add it because it wasn't clear from this statement, "(only) this "import"-folders should be copied to a destination directory". I therefore left all options, for [tag:robocopy] out, for you to include as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Below you have a simple code in Powershell that copies the folder with it's content and add a number to the folder in the destination.
Was it something like that you were looking for?

Below script is a one-shot-deal and would fail if you run it twice (the number would start again at 1).
You can simply ad a `If-statement` to check for used names if you want to run it multiple times.

```
$source = "SOURCE PATH"
$destination = "DESTINATION PATH"
$foldername = "FOLDERNAME"
$number = 0

$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $foldername}
Foreach ($folder in $folders){
    $number++
    Copy-Item -Path $folder -Destination $destination -Recurse
    Rename-Item -Path "$destination\$foldername" -NewName "$foldername $Number"
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you, I tried your Power-Shell solution as well - the script does not seem to pass the source path fully to the Copy-Item command. I got:  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\temp\import:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand  - so its trying to copy "import" from the directory that I execute the script from. But as the solution posted by Compo is working, I am already happy. Just wanted to let you know.

Comment: Hi! Glad it worked out.
Regarding the script you need to move the path one step up since it's using recurse (searching in below folders). It won't find anything otherwise, so in your case `$source` should be "C:\Temp"

Comment: Hi! I did use the full source path in $source - but even then, it's trying to pick "import-Folder" from "one level above" - so when I use c:\copytest as $source and the structure is C:\COPYTEST\AAA\import, the error message would be ObjectNotFound: (C:\COPYTEST\import:String)

Comment: Can you paste your entire code below? Must be something else that is off

Comment: Hi! Executing the script from c:\script

code:
`$source = "C:\TESTCOPY"
$destination = "C:\temp"
$foldername = "import"
$number = 0

$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $foldername}
Foreach ($folder in $folders){
    $number++
    Copy-Item -Path $folder -Destination $destination -Recurse
    Rename-Item -Path "$destination\$foldername" -NewName "$foldername $Number"
}$`

Error:
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\scripts\import' because it does not exist.
At C:\scripts\testcopy.ps1:9 char:5

Answer (score 0):

Although user [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015)'s [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62194060) is probably the smartest solution, I want to provide a script that applies unique random numbers to the sub-directories `import*` in the destination directory:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=.\Source"
set "_TARGET=.\Destination"
set "_SUBDIR=import"

rem // Reset array variables:
for /F "delims==" %%E in ('2^> nul ^(set "$DIR[" ^& set "$RND["^)') do set "%%E="

rem // Build array of source sub-directories:
set /A "CNT=0"
for /D %%J in ("%_SOURCE%\*") do (
    for %%I in ("%%~J\%_SUBDIR%") do (
        set "ATTR=%%~aI" & set "ITEM=%%~fI"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if defined ATTR if "!ATTR:~,1!"=="d" (
            for /F "delims=" %%E in ("$DIR[!CNT!]=!ITEM!") do (
                endlocal & set "%%E"
            )
            set /A "CNT+=1"
        ) else endlocal
    )
)

rem // Build array of unique random numbers:
set /A "CNT-=1"
for /L %%R in (0,1,%CNT%) do (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set /A "RND=(!RANDOM!<<16)+(!RANDOM!<<2)+!RANDOM!%%2"
    for /F "delims=" %%E in ("$RND[!RND!_%%R]=%%R") do (
        endlocal & set "%%E"
    )
)

rem // Copy source sub-direcgtories to destination using random names:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /A "CNT=0"
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%R in ('2^> nul set "$RND["') do (
    > nul xcopy /Y /E /I "!$DIR[%%R]!" "!_TARGET!\!_SUBDIR!!CNT!"
    set /A "CNT+=1"
    )
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

If you are satisfied with sequential numbers, with respect to the order the file system returns the matching sub-directories (usually alphabetic in modern systems file like NTFS), you could use this script instead:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=.\Source"
set "_TARGET=.\Destination"
set "_SUBDIR=import"

rem // Build array of source sub-directories:
set /A "CNT=0"
for /D %%J in ("%_SOURCE%\*") do (
    for %%I in ("%%~J\%_SUBDIR%") do (
        set "ATTR=%%~aI" & set "ITEM=%%~fI"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if defined ATTR if "!ATTR:~,1!"=="d" (
            > nul xcopy /Y /E /I "!ITEM!" "!_TARGET!\!_SUBDIR!!CNT!"
            endlocal & set /A "CNT+=1"
        ) else endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```